# Is there a oneliner to create a SortedSet filled with one or multiple elements in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I am just asking myself if there is a more convenient way to create a `SortedSet`, e.g. a `TreeSet` in Java than the one liner I am currently using in tests:

```
new TreeSet<>(Set.of(element1, element2));
```

Something like `SortedSet.of(...)` maybe from Apache Commons or the like?

Comment: You can define a static method like `getSortedSet()` which returns a TreeSet with the required data. Then you can use the method in your tests.

Comment: Are you looking for Guava's ImmutableSortedSet.of?

Comment: What’s wrong with `new TreeSet<>(Set.of(element1, element2))`? Why do you think the alternative of the accepted answer (`Sets.newTreeSet(ImmutableSet.of(1, 2, 3))`) is better than that?

Comment: I would love to have a more compact solution ideally from the JDK itself. But this is what I already mentioned.
Using this in complex builder structures makes code unreadable pretty fast.

Comment: And why did you accept an answer showing a “solution” that is in no way “more compact”, but in fact, even longer?

Comment: I cannot see how the accepted answer is shorter (better or even *different*) than the code in question, just using some library (which I would consider more complicated) Actually I do not think shorter code is possible (but creating a method to *hide* that one-liner)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use a library like `Guava`:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import java.util.SortedSet;

SortedSet<Integer> sortedSet = Sets.newTreeSet(ImmutableSet.of(1, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will be considered better in the simple case (without Comparator), but you can use `SortedSets` from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
SortedSet<Integer> sortedSet = SortedSets.mutable.of(1, 2, 3);
SortedSet<Integer> expected =  new TreeSet<>(Set.of(1, 2, 3));

Assertions.assertEquals(expected, sortedSet);
```

A `SortedSet` can also be created in a one-liner with a `Comparator`.

```
SortedSet<Integer> reversed = 
    SortedSets.mutable.of(Comparator.reverseOrder(), 1, 2, 3);

SortedSet<Integer> expected = 
    new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
expected.addAll(Set.of(1, 2, 3));

Assertions.assertEquals(expected, reversed);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.